# How to replicate this UI with curve edges

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend

just wanted a little bit of help for this UI I'm trying to replicate. I know this can be achieved using css clip path but can't seem to figure out how can I replicate the curved edges using css clip path because of its nature.

Here's the screenshot of the UI I'm trying to replicate:

[image: This sample]
[image: And this sample]

For the longest time I can't seem to figure out how this could be done.

I've used sites like [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to try and replicate it but the predefined and sample shapes were too pointy that I can't basically use it as reference.

Answer (score 2):

So yes, `clip-path` can help you create the effect you want. Design your path in an SVG editor (such as [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com)), then just copy-paste the path into your CSS.

```css
.d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: path('M 100 100 C 100 108.284 93.284 115 85 115 C 76.716 115 70 108.284 70 100 C 70 91.716 76.716 85 85 85 C 93.284 85 100 91.716 100 100 Z M 100 200 L 100 160 C 99.994 150.156 95.322 149.925 90 150 C 20 150 20 50 90 50 C 100 50 99.88 45.308 100 40 L 100 0 L 0 0 L 0 200');
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question and thought that I really was a cool looking navigation bar, so, I tried to make it myself, here is my attempt at it.

Oh and, yeah, it's not that good looking, but you can play with the border radii that I put to make it look better. If you don't know how they work let me know.

It probably isn't the best and could by optimized a LOT, but I already spent too much time on that haha. I think this answer should make you happy :)

Let me know if you have some more questions about something I did, or if you want me to optimize something in here!

```js
let selectedLink = document.querySelector(".selectedLink");

function checkActive() {
  document.querySelectorAll("nav li").forEach((item) => {
    if (item.dataset.active == "true") {
      selectedLink.style.transform = `translateX(${
        item.offsetLeft + item.offsetWidth / 2 - 24 + "px"
      })`;
    }
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll("nav li").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("nav li").forEach((i) => {
      i.dataset.active = "false";
    });
    e.currentTarget.dataset.active = "true";
    checkActive();
  });
});

checkActive();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  background: royalblue;
}

nav {
  min-width: 28rem;
  background: white;
  color: #0e0e0e;
  border-radius: 100vw;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #0e0e0e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.selectedLink {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: royalblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.selectedLink .side {
  background: royalblue;
  width: 1.5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}

.side.left {
  left: -50%;
}

.side.right {
  right: -50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.selectedLink .outside {
  background: royalblue;
  width: 1.5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  clip-path: polygon(79% 25%, 30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.outside.left {
  left: -140%;
}

.outside.right {
  right: -140%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.selectedLink .outside::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0 / 0 50% 0 0;
}

.selectedLink .dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <div class="selectedLink">
            <div class="side left"></div>
            <div class="side right"></div>
            <div class="outside left"></div>
            <div class="outside right"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </div>
          <li data-active="true"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li data-active="false"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li data-active="false"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```